# Apply column min and column max to every row in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, max, min, array-column

I need to find the minimum value in one column and the maximum value in another column of a two-dimensional array and apply those values to every row in the array.

Sample input:

```
$array = [
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 1, "name" => "Ram"],
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 2, "name" => "Raj"],
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 3, "name" => "Rahul"],
    ["day1" => 2, "day2" => 3, "name" => "Rocky"]
];
```

In the above data set, the minimum `day1` value is `1` and the maximum `day2` value is `3`.  I need to apply those two values (respective to their column) to the `day1` and `day2` values in every rows.

Expected output:

```
[
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 3, "name" => "Ram"],
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 3, "name" => "Raj"],
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 3, "name" => "Rahul"],
    ["day1" => 1, "day2" => 3, "name" => "Rocky"]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help -

```
$data=array(array("day1"=>1,"day2"=>1,"name"=>"Ram"),array("day1"=>1,"day2"=>2,"name"=>"Raj"),array("day1"=>1,"day2"=>3,"name"=>"Rahul"),array("day1"=>2,"day2"=>3,"name"=>"Rocky"));
// Get all values for day1 & day2 and store them in one array
$values = array_merge(array_column($data, 'day2'), array_column($data, 'day1'));
// Assign values
$data = array_map(function($d) use($values) {
    // Assign the minimum value
    $d['day1'] = min($values);
    // assign the maximum value
    $d['day2'] = max($values);
    return $d;
}, $data);

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Output**

```
[{"day1":1,"day2":3,"name":"Ram"},{"day1":1,"day2":3,"name":"Raj"},{"day1":1,"day2":3,"name":"Rahul"},{"day1":1,"day2":3,"name":"Rocky"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help:  check the **[demo](https://eval.in/717703)**

```
    $data=array(array("day1"=>1,"day2"=>1,"name"=>"Ram"),array("day1"=>1,"day2"=>2,"name"=>"Raj"),array("day1"=>1,"day2"=>3,"name"=>"Rahul"),array("day1"=>2,"day2"=>3,"name"=>"Rocky"));
    $min = min(array_column($data, 'day1'));
    $max = max(array_column($data, 'day2'));
    $result = array_map(function($v) use($min, $max){$v['day1'] = $min; $v['day2'] = $max; return $v; }, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple cycles (`foreach()` loops and or `array_column()` calls), this task can be completed in 1 cycle by declaring reference variables at all elements which need to be updated with the min/max values.

Below, the final iteration's `$day1` and `$day2` values will be distributed to all points of reference.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BmESHk))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $day1 = min($day1 ?? $row['day1'], $row['day1']);
    $day2 = max($day2 ?? $row['day2'], $row['day2']);
    $row['day1'] = &$day1;
    $row['day2'] = &$day2;
}
var_export($array);
```